# Comparar si una Matriz es simetrica al invertirla

Tags: c#

Hola estoy realizando un ejercicio donde debo validar si una matriz array ya creado es asimetrico o no, tengo lo siguiente pero me parece que no tengo muy claro la solicitud, me parece que debo recorrer valor por valor y yo lo que estoy haciendo es invirtiendo completamente.

Lo que se me pide es esto:

> Escribir un programa en CSharp que puede determinar si una matriz es
> simétrica. Una matriz es simétrica si se ve igual si está invertida.
> Por ejemplo ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a') es simétrica y
> ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'a') no lo es. Suponga que n será
> siempre un número par entre 2 y 10 (No hay necesidad de validar esto).
> Si es simétrico su programa debe imprimir 'Symmetric', de lo contrario
> imprimir 'Asymmetric'

y lo que tengo en código es esto:

```
using System;

namespace Ejercicios_de_logica
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] myArray = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c", "b", "b" };
            int n = 2;

            string[] myArray2 = myArray;

            int length = myArray2.Length;

            Array.Reverse(myArray2);

            Console.WriteLine("Array invertido:\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (myArray != myArray2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Es asimetrico");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Es Simetrico");
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Console.WriteLine(myArray2[i]);
            //Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);
            Console.ReadKey();



        }
    }
}
```

Agradezco si me pueden guiar sobre cómo realizar lo que se me pide más exacto.

NOTA: la matriz se debe de comparar consigo misma, por ejemplo:

{ "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c", "b", "b" };

Aquí comienza con "a" y termina con "b" por lo tanto no es asimetrica al verse inversa, pero al parecer lo que estoy haciendo es creando 2 matrices una invertida y comparando, por lo tanto siempre me dice que es simetrica.

Comment: Porque los break si vos qures comprobar hasta el final? simplifica el problema.. supone que es simetrica siempre (crea una variable booleana) y dentro del for, fijate si falla la simetria, cambia esa variable y listo...

Comment: @gbianchi disculpa pero no me quedó tan claro la idea que me comentas.

Comment: Arriesgándome a sonar pedante, creo que hay que mejorar la definición de **matriz simétrica**. De acuerdo con Wikipedia, una [matriz es simétrica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_sim%C3%A9trica), cuando la matriz **es igual a su traspuesta**. Para esto, tiene que ser una matriz cuadrada, es decir, tiene el mismo numero de filas y columnas. Tiene que verse igual de ambos lados utilizando la diagonal principal. La matriz que pones de ejemplo **no es simétrica**. Lo que estás buscando parece ser un arreglo [palíndromo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pal%C3%ADndromo)

Comment: Revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: @Arriel, el op debió decir vector

Comment: @Japv, puede que la crítica sea más hacia el sistema educativo. Be that as it may, creo es importante utilizar los términos adecuados.

Comment: Hola Thanatos, podrias decirnos si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles y marcar como aceptada la que mas te haya ayudado y si lo deseas puedes emitir tu voto tambie, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Es bastante simple, sólo revisa si los elementos coinciden con su simétrico. Es decir, el primero con el último, el segundo con el penúltimo y así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si todos son iguales, entonces tienes que es simétrico. De lo contrario es asimétrico. Lo mejor es que funciona para arreglos pares e impares, no necesitas crear un segundo arreglo y funciona con la mitad de operaciones (si hay 16 elementos sólo haces 8 operaciones)

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    string[] myArray = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c", "b", "a" };
    // Como comparas el primero con el último 
    // el segundo con el penúltimo y así,
    // sólo debes de recorrer hasta la mitad de tu arreglo
    int length = myArray.Length / 2;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (myArray[i] != myArray[myArray.Length - i - 1]) {
            Console.WriteLine("Es asimétrico");
            return;
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("Es simétrico");
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar **Linq**, de esta forma ahorrarás mucho código:

```
var simetrico = myArreglo.SecuenceEqual(myArreglo.Reverse());

if(simetrico)
{
  // Imprimir qué hay simetría 
}
else
{
  // Imprimir que no hay simetría 
}
```

La **función Reverse** invierte el arreglo y usando la **función SequenceEqual**, se determina si la secuencia original y la inversa son o no simétricas.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings:**

```
using System.Linq;
```

En **caso de no usar Linq**, prueba lo siguiente:

```
var inverso = myArreglo.Reverse();
int cont = 0;
int i = 0;

while(i < myArreglo.Count() && inverso[i] == myArreglo[i])
{
   cont++;
   i++;
}

if(cont == myArreglo.Count())
{
   //Simétrico 
}
else
{
   //No simétrico 
}
```

Hallas el inverso del arreglo y ejecutarás un **ciclo while** que correrá mientras los elementos de ambos arreglos sean iguales en las mismas posiciones, de cumplirse la condición del **ciclo while** se incrementa la **variable cont**.

Al salir del **ciclo while** se pregunta si la **variable cont** es igual a la cantidad de elementos de cualquiera de los arreglos, de ser iguales es simétrico, caso contrario no lo es.

Comment: El problema es que no debo de usar Linq

Comment: @Thanatos9516, revisa lo nuevo que puse

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo tu código está bastante bien. Yo haría algo como esto en la parte del final:

```
bool asimetrico = false;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if (myArray[i] != myArray2[i])
    {
        asimetrico = true;
        break;
    } 
}

if (asimetrico){
   Console.WriteLine("Es asimetrico");
else {
   Console.WriteLine("Es simetrico");
}
```

De todas formas hace rato que no toco C#, puede que haya cometido algún error. Saludos.

Comment: Según mi lógica es como lo comentas pero veo que no importa que valor lleve la matriz, de igual manera me dice que es simetrico y en teoría debe de compararse con ella misma de un lado para otro, así coloque: { "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c", "b", "b" };  me dice que es simetrico y en ese caso debería de tirarme que no lo es ya que no termina con "a" como al inicio

Comment: Fijate que en mi ejemplo le agregué [i] a cada arreglo en el if del for, en tu código original no está. Probaste ejecutarlo de la forma en que te pasé? Debería funcionar.

Comment: También lo que podés hacer es usando un solo arreglo, tener dos índices, un i y un j. Dentro de un bucle, vas incrementando i y disminuyendo j, haciendo que i tome el primer elemento del arreglo y j el último. De esa forma se compara el primer elemento con el último, el segundo con el anteúltimo y así.